# Full screen video url youtube android not working

Tags: android, url, video, youtube, fullscreen

I want to show fullscreen youtube video in videowebview in my app , I've tried this code:

```
 youtubeVideos.add( new YouTubeVideos("<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/"VIDEO-URL" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>") );
```

But unfortunately its not working(in web browser its working).
can someone help me?

Comment: can someone help me ? its important for me

Comment: are you using any library?

Comment: Im not using any library